# how to insert value in DB when session is expired

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

In my work from login, I use an authentication jsp page where I am setting the max inactive time as 60 to prevent multiple logins from a single username.

I have created a field `status` in DB so when a user logs in then the status will be active and no other user can login from the same username.

Now my problem is how to set the status as inactive in the DB when the session expires.

To update status inactive I did

```
login=(String)session.getAttribute("login");

PreparedStatement pt = con.prepareStatement("update authentication set status='inactive' where username='"+login+"'");
```

So when the session is expired, then login will give null. Please tell me how to solve my problem

Comment: Please see [A Simple HttpSessionListener Example – Active Sessions Counter](http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/a-simple-httpsessionlistener-example-active-sessions-counter/).

Comment: @CharleeChitsuk thanks for the link,i have one doubt please. for updating the status as inactive i will write this update authentication set status='inactive' where username='"+login+"'"
in sessionDestroyed method.Please tell me how to get the login value

Comment: @w4rumy i could not understand it

Answer (score 2):

Use  [**HttpSessionActivationListener**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionActivationListener.html)

```
     public void sessionDidActivate(HttpSessionEvent se)
```

> Notification that the session has just been activated.

```
     public void sessionWillPassivate(HttpSessionEvent se)
```

> Notification that the session is about to be passivated.

or

[**HttpSessionListener**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html)

```
     sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se)
```

> Receives notification that a session has been created.

```
     sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se)
```

> Receives notification that a session is about to be invalidated.

Comment: have you gone through mkyong exmple  http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/a-simple-httpsessionlistener-example-active-sessions-counter/?

Comment: Check out the links in this answer.  They point you to pages that describe interfaces that you could implement.  For example, you could implement an HttpSessionListener and execute your prepared statement in the _sessionDestroyed_ method.

Comment: @Baadshah yes i have gone throgh the link but i am not getting how to get the login value

Comment: @jahroy please tell me how to get the attribute value

Comment: @jahroy see when the session is created then i am storing the username as session.setAttribute("login",username)
and when i am using prepared statement in sessionDestroyed method i need attribute value

Comment: @javaL use the `HttpSessionEvent` parameter which is passed in `sessionDestroyed` to get the session which will be destroyed. There you can also access the login value.

Comment: @w4rumy can you please tell me in detail